# I have an array of string that I want to display one at a time on a keypress using any key alphanumeric

Tags: jquery, arrays, keypress

I'm not sure if this the correct way to import the messages. Using any key instead of enter:

```
use strict";
var queue = lyrics; 

$(document).keyup(function){
    if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 90){
        var val= queu.shift();
        $(".lyrics").append(val);
    }
})

var lyrics =[
        "I took a vow that from now on Im gonna be my own best friend",
        "Perfection is the disease of a nation",
        "I took some time to live my life. But dont think Im just his little wife.",
        "There's nothing not to love about me. I'm lovely.",
        "My persuasion can build a nation.",
        "Some call it arrogant. I call it confident",
        "Goddammit I'm comfortable in my skin",
        "Stop making a big deal out of the little things",
        "I wake up looking this good. And I wouldn't change it if I could",
        "A little sweat ain't never hurt nobody"
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var lyrics =[
        "I took a vow that from now on Im gonna be my own best friend",
        "Perfection is the disease of a nation",
        "I took some time to live my life. But dont think Im just his little wife.",
        "There's nothing not to love about me. I'm lovely.",
        "My persuasion can build a nation.",
        "Some call it arrogant. I call it confident",
        "Goddammit I'm comfortable in my skin",
        "Stop making a big deal out of the little things",
        "I wake up looking this good. And I wouldn't change it if I could",
        "A little sweat ain't never hurt nobody"
    ];
    $(document).on('keyup', function(event){
      if ( lyrics.length ) {
        if ( event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 90 ) {
          $('.lyrics').append(lyrics.shift());
        }
      } else {
        console.log('no more lyrics');
      }
    });
```